# ASP.NET and C# Streaming from database

Tags: c#, asp.net, streaming

How can i read a mp3 file from a database and streaming it in a website project?

Comment: By programming? Please define streaming. You mean http (fake) streaming, or real RTP based streaming?

Answer (score 2):

Check this feature of SQL server. help you to achieve your task

[An Introduction to SQL Server FileStream](http://www.simple-talk.com/sql/learn-sql-server/an-introduction-to-sql-server-filestream/)